# How could I combine columns but only sort using one in Sheets?

Tags: google-sheets

I'm trying to sort a list of names by length of first name (in characters), but keep the first and last names together. For example:

```
Unsorted
Andrew Jackson
John Smith 
Abraham Lincoln
```

---

```
Sorted
John Smith
Andrew Jackson
Abraham Lincoln
```

Currently, I have all of the first names in the A column and all of the last names in the B column.

Originally, I used `=SORT({A:A,len(A:A)},2,false)` to sort just the first names, which worked. But I'd like to keep the last names with the first names.

Answer (score 0):

Try `QUERY()` function with few other functions.

```
=QUERY({INDEX(LEN(INDEX(SPLIT(A2:A4," "),,1))),A2:A4},"select Col2 order by Col1")
```

Or `SORT()` function with `INDEX()` and `SPLIT()`.

```
=INDEX(SORT({INDEX(LEN(INDEX(SPLIT(A2:A4," "),,1))),A2:A4},1,1),,2)
```

[image]